# jQuery - position of clicked item

Tags: jquery, position

in a script i am using following code is used to position a popup window in the middle of the screen.

i'd need to change this in a way that the `Y` position is the same as the item i clicked on. so if i click on an item the popup should be displayed at the same height as the item i clicked. i have no clue about jquery and 2 hours of trying didnt help. any help appreciated

i marked the line that needs to be edited.

```
                switch(a)
            {
                case 'postdetails':
                case 'userdetails':
                    $('#reputation-popup').addClass('normal-popup');
                    targetleft = ($(window).width() - $('#reputation-popup').outerWidth()) / 2;
                    targettop = ($(window).height() - $('#reputation-popup').outerHeight()) / 2;
                    /////// THE LINE ABOVE THIS IS THE ONE I NEED TO EDIT!!!! //////////

                break;
                case 'newpopup':
                    $('#reputation-popup').addClass('new-popup');
                    targetleft = ($(window).width() - $('#reputation-popup').outerWidth()) / 2;
                    targettop = ($(window).height() - $('#reputation-popup').outerHeight()) / 2;
                break;
                default:
                    $('#reputation-popup').addClass('small-popup');
                    // Center popup relative to clicked coordinate
                    targetleft = c.pageX - $('#reputation-popup').outerWidth() / 2;
                    // Popup can not be too close or behind the right border of the screen
                    targetleft = Math.min (targetleft, $(document).width() - 20 - $('#reputation-popup').outerWidth());
                    targetleft = Math.max (targetleft, 20);
                    targettop = c.pageY + 10;
                break;
            }
```

Comment: Too much code redundancy. Try to isolate the centering code inside a function and call it with the selector of the popup you need centered.

Comment: Could you show some of your (relevant) HTML upon which this is supposed to work? And perhaps post a (minimal/[sscce](http://sscce.org/)) [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) with which we can work/experiment? Please: help us to help you.

Comment: i'm sorry, this is a premade script installed on phpbb board. so i have no clue on what you need. the board is on http://www.stockuploader.com/forums/ and the popup is supposed to appear when you click on the "0" in each post of the board.

Comment: basically i need the popup to be displayed ON the post i clicked, as an absolute position, not to float on the middle of the screen. this is the script i installed : https://github.com/Pico88/phpBB-Reputation-System the file is styles/prosilver/template/reputation/jquery.reputation.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#item1').click(function(){
     // GETS POSITION OF CLICKED ITEM
     var offset = this.offset();
     var x = offset.left;
     var y = offset.top;
     // GETS THE DIMENSION OF THE CLICKED ITEM
     var w = this.width();
     var h = this.height();
     // APPLY THE SETTINGS TO ITEM2 USING CSS FUNCTION
     $('#item2').css({
         .....
     });
    // http://api.jquery.com/css/

});
```

Answer (score 1):

try with :

```
 $("item").offset().top;
 $("item").offset().left;
```

more info here:http://api.jquery.com/offset/

Comment: thanks! is "item" generic or do i have to replace it with something? how can i know what item has been cliked?

Comment: yes you need to replace tem with your cliked item, to know which one is clicked you can use $(this) for example and replace item with $(this): like that :$(this).offset().top;

Comment: doesnt seem to work. for a reason i dont know the popup is palced at the end of the page. is there a way to show a message box to see the value it is reading?

Comment: make alert for example to c the value : alert("Top:"$("item").offset().top+" Left:"+$("item").offset().left);

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following jQuery functions to position your popup menu:

1) event.pageX, event.pageY gives you the mouse position relative to document

Ref : http://api.jquery.com/event.pageY/

2) offset() : It gives the offset position of an element

Ref : http://api.jquery.com/offset/

3) position() : It gives you the relative Position of an element

Ref : http://api.jquery.com/position/